# pass a java parameter from maven

Tags: java, maven

I need to execute some tests with maven, and pass a parameter from the command line.

My java code should get the parameter as:
System.getenv("my_parameter1");

and I define the parameter in the pom.xml file as the example below:
(and latter, I'd modify the pom.xml to get the parameter from the common line mvn clean install -Dmy_parameter1=value1)

but it does not work; System.getenv("my_parameter1") returns null.
how should I define the parameter in the pom.xml file?

pom.xml

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <properties>
        <my_parameter1>value1</my_parameter1>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>slowTest</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <skip>false</skip>
                  <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*TestSlow.java</include>
                  </includes>
                  <properties>
                    <my_parameter1>value1</my_parameter1>
                  </properties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[System.getenv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29)() reads *environment variables*, such as `PATH`.  What you want is to read a *system property* instead.  The -D[system property name]=[value] is for system properties, not environment variables.

You have two options:

1. If you want to use environment variables, use the OS-specific method of setting the environment variable `my_parameter1` before you launch Maven.  In Windows, use `set my_parameter1=<value>`, in 'nix use `export my_parameter1=<value>`.
2. You can use [System.getProperty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) to read the system property value from within your code.

example:

```
String param = System.getProperty("my_parameter1");
```

In you surefire plugin configuration, you can use:

```
<configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <my_property1>${my_property1}</my_property1>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

Which takes the Maven property _my_property1_ and sets it also in your tests.

More details about this [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).

I'm not sure if system properties from Maven are automatically passed to tests and/or whether fork mode affects whether this happens, so it's probably a good idea to pass them in explicitly.

Comment: Just checked: Maven system properties are *not* automatically passed to the tests.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
${env.my_parameter}
```

to access the environment variable in the pom.xml.

You can use the help plugin to see which variables are set with

```
mvn help:system
```

However the normal properties usage should work too. In the large context however I am wondering... what do you want to do? There might be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

The maven surefire plugin also has an [option to set environment variables](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#environmentVariables), just add this to your plugin configuration.

```
<environmentVariables>
    <my_parameter1>value</my_parameter1>
</environmentVariables>
```

I think this requires that the plugin operates in [fork mode](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkMode), which is the default.

Comment: +1 for the fork mode... It's not written in the doc.