# Junit excluded tests are not shown up as Skipped

Tags: maven, junit, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

We have a typical Maven/Surefire/Junit setup. We have categorized some of the tests as SlowTests with [Junit categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories) feature.

When we run the test(mvn test) the default behavior is to skip the SlowTests. We have done this by defining "excludedGroups" in surefire definition.

I thought that in the test output, the excluded tests will count towards number of "Skipped" tests. But the "Skipped" tests are always shown as '0'!!

How to make these excluded tests to count towards "Skipped" tests? In general, when will Junit/Surefire show "Skipped" tests > 0?

Answer (score 1):

*Skipped* means that the test was a candidate for Surefire to execute, but an `@Ignore` was found or an [`Assume`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) statement failed.

If you want your slow tests to appear as skipped, you could use Maven to set a system property and test for that with an `Assume` statement in a `@BeforeClass` method. Perhaps your slow tests could extend a parent class which performs this check.

The Surefire plugin can also set environment variables if you want to do it that way, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622482/474189.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Ignore above the test method. Something like that:

```
   @Ignore
   @Test
   public void test method() {}
```

Comment: If I add @Ignore, I can not optionally run them from command line. With "excludeGroups" I can change the behavior from command line with a property