# How to display the current Build number from Jenkins into JSP

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jenkins

I am trying to get and display the current build number from Jenkins into a jsp. I have come to know that jenkins have the environment variable `BUILD_NUMBER` which potentially can give me what I am looking for but how can I display it in a jsp.

May I do something like ${BUILD_NUMBER} in my jsp, so after running the Maven build command in Jenkins the build number would show up?

I don't have any code to show.

Thanks.

Comment: The below link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510690/environment-variable-with-maven
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622121/pass-a-java-parameter-from-maven

Comment: This is not what I am doing.