# How to fix system.getenv error while running through maven command?

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber, getenv, getproperty

I am running a project on eclipse through maven and I have set an environment variable on my system for my project to work.

Here is a sample code:

```
public class StepDefFile {

    WebDriver driver = CaptureScreenshot.driver;
    public static String configFilePath =System.getenv("configFilePath");

    @Given(Login to application")
    public void Login_to_application() throws Throwable {
        driver = Helper.initializeDriver(); 
    }
}
```

But when i run `mvn test` I am getting java `nullPointerException` as it is unable to find the `config.properties` file while running the test.

**Please check below image for maven error log**

[image]

I have already tried solutions from below links but it did not work for me:

[pass a java parameter from maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622121/pass-a-java-parameter-from-maven)

[Environment Variable with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510690/environment-variable-with-maven/5510702)

My `pom.xml` file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>name</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**In continuation to above pom**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <configFilePath>${env.configFilePath}</configFilePath>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <includes>
                            <include>RunnerTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

**In continuation to above pom**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-plugin-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xpp3/xpp3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4c</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

I want to run the above code through maven by passing my configuration file as an environment variable.

Comment: Add all error messages as text into the question. No images.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in `WebDriver driver = CaptureScreenshot.driver;`?

Comment: Have you restarted the machine after creating the "configFilePath" environment variable?

Comment: @supputuri : Yes this worked. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always makes sure to restart the machine when you add system environment variable, which you are planning to access in your script.

Here is the detailed reason:

`This behavior occurs because services that run under the Local System account inherit their environment from the Services.exe process. The Services.exe process receives the environment settings for the Local System account when Windows starts. Because the Services.exe process does not use Windows Messaging, when it receives messages that indicate that a value has changed after Windows starts, the Services.exe process does not update its environment settings. You cannot force a service that is running to acknowledge a dynamic change to the environment of the Local System account.`(source Microsoft support website)